# Cannot use illuminate\Databasemodel\Model as Model because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel

I have some data in my database that I want to preserve via a migration, and I am using iSeed to help me produce seeds from the data. However, when I try to run the seeds using

```
php artisan db:seed
```

I get an error, which says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use Illuminate\DatabaseModel\Model as Model because the name is already in use in laravel/app/User.php on line 7

So, I went into User.php, and changed this line(which is actually line 6, not line 7):

```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

to this:

```
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;
```

I also changed it to extend BaseModel instead of Model. 
The weird thing is that I still get the same error, still for User.php. I have tried running composer dumpautoload, but this did not help. As far as my understanding goes, using it as BaseController should have fixed the issue, but it didn't. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Edit: Including full code for the model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\DatabaseModel\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you see this particular error? Because there is no such namespace in Laravel like `Illuminate\DatabaseModel\Model`

Comment: I am quite sure -- I copy and pasted that straight from my browser's window. I did notice that the namespace looks a bit weird, but I'm not that experienced with laravel so I figured it was something going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you show the whole code of your model?

Comment: @max.lanin I have edited the question to include the full model code.

Comment: Remove this line `use Illuminate\DatabaseModel\Model;`

Comment: Did you run composer dump-autoload -o ?